# properties of object variables how to target them

Tags: javascript, object

What I'm given in my homework is and JS object that looks like:

```
myObj = 

    {name:eric, location:belgium, age:24},
    {name:jools, location:holland, age26},
    {name:mike, location:usa, age:30},
```

the idea is that somehow if i need to target 'location' holland i need to be able to treat all this like an arary so I can work with indexes (at least that's what I think). I Can't find any example anywhere where people work with this been searching for a bit on 'js object'.

The actual challenge is to be able to put the different values of the 'name' property as innerHTML(or some method that does something similar) of new option elements inside a given select element probably through a loop. Since this is homework, I don't need the actual code for that but a clue on where I can  learn more about how these JS object property array type of things work would be nice.

thanks a lot!

Comment: That JavaScript snippet is invalid. Did you introduce errors during copying and pasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript snippet is invalid, something makes me think there was a copy-and-paste error. The answer changes significantly depending on what the code *actually* looks like.

If it looks like this:

```
myObj = [

    {name:eric, location:belgium, age:24},
    {name:jools, location:holland, age26},
    {name:mike, location:usa, age:30},
    // ...
    ];
```

...then you're dealing with an array of objects, where each object has the properties `name` and `location`. You can loop through them using a standard `for` loop with an index variable, counting from `0` to `myObj.length - 1` (inclusive), and access the properties of each object via `myObj[index].name` and `myObj[index].location`.

Comment: Excellent! the sqaure braces weren't even in the assignment so not even my mistake. this solved it. Thanks a lot!